# MSS and tcp window size

Tags: networking, tcp

during communication between A and B ,
When A is sending data to B , the segment size is going to depend on B's window size.
Initially , after B successfully receives data, it doubles window size and this continues.
Now B knows its MSS. So while sending the segment size to A, it can make sure that it does not exceed MSS value. 
Then why B has to inform MSS to A at the first place ?

Comment: This question is off-topic to Stack Overflow, as it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 8):

Segment size depends on the MTU size of the data link layer of the networks the sender and the receiver are each attached to.

Path MTU Discovery can be used to discover the minimum MTU size between the sender and receiver to dynamically determine the optimum Maximum Segment Size (avoiding IP fragmentation) between the sender and receiver (assuming that all routers between the sender and the receiver honour the do_not_fragment bit).

You appear to be conflating flow control and sliding windows with Maximum Segment Size.

---

**Update** based on comments.

> Is it that Window size cannot exceed the MSS ? I fail to find relation between them.

No, that's not it.

> Is it that window size purely depends on the buffer size at sender and receiver and MSS depends on the MTU?

MSS and MTU size are terms that require context because they have different implications depending on context.

While considering just one direction of transfer, there are two "windows" to consider:

- **Receive Window**. Used to implement [Flow Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control), maintained and specified by the receiver. It is constrained by the ability of the receiver to buffer from one moment to the next. The receive window defines how much data can be sent before being acknowledged by the sender. See also [BDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product). The MSS has no bearing on the receive window.
- **Congestion Window**. Used to implement [Congestion Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Congestion_control). Maintained and used by the sender. The Congestion window size is effectively a multiple of the MSS.

> Window size for both A and B can be different but MSS remamins same because of the common link they share?

There's no requirement for MSS to be symmetric. There's no guarantee or requirement that the path taken is same from A to B as it is from B to A.

I recommend that you read the entire article here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol as there are diagrams to aid understanding.

Comment: Not to mention that several major routing systems have TCP MSS adjustment options to avoid fragmentation, completely unrelated to throughput.

Comment: @MattH :Is it that Window size cannot exceed the MSS ? I fail to find relation between them. Is it that window size purely depends on the buffer size at sender and receiver and MSS depends on the MTU ? and window size for both A and B can be different but MSS remamins same because of the common link they share ?

Comment: @script_kiddie No it isn't true. Why do you even ask? He's already specifically addressed that.

Answer (score 2):

> the segment size is going to depend on B's window size

*And* on the path MTU. The lower of these two numbers applies. The path MTU is constant for a given path; the advertised window size is dynamic according to the state of the receiver's socket receive buffer, slow start, etc.